# How to configure css modules in my React app

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

Im not using the create react app project. Here is my webpack.base.js (someone else set this up so im just working off what i have)

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    target: "web",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/opt/valkyrie/html"),
        clean: true
    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: '**/node_modules',
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ["src", "node_modules"],
        extensions: [
            ".tsx",
            ".ts",
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".svg",
            ".css",
            ".json",
            ".mdx",
            ".png",
            ".scss",
            ".sass"
        ],
        alias: {
            react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    "style-loader",
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "css-loader",
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '/public/icons/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },

        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Spectrum App",
            template: __dirname + "/public/index.html",
            inject: "body",
            filename: "index.html",
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css",
        }),
    ]
};
```

Can someone tell me how I turn on css modules? Googling around i see a number of posts about turning it on for the create react app but they mention existing settings that i dont have in mine.
Im using React 17.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Add this to webpack module

```html
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css'],
        include: `${__dirname}/src`,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
```

and please rename the css files as `component_name.module.css` and import the css file in jsx/js as `import styles from './component_name.module.css'`;

Comment: I put it above the rules property in module but i get an error: 
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'.

Comment: These properties are valid:
   object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, generator?, noParse?, parser?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }

Comment: okay then try removing the code which i gave from webpack and follow the further process i gave u (renaming css files and importing it in that way)

Comment: Cannot find module './App.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations - because there is nothing to tell it to look for xxx.module.css